# Attach image to custom area with a free transform

Tags: konvajs

please assist me to complete it, i need free image transform, i have did main logic but not sure how to complete it. Image must be inside of my custom selection.

so i set only left top corner, but object havent additional x's and y's, for example x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4

`image.setAttrs({
                    x: dashed.leftTop.attrs.x,
                    y: dashed.leftTop.attrs.y
                });`

i'm not sure how i can set neccessary corners. or there another way to complete it?

please help me to use skew with it?

https://jsfiddle.net/u9ck6b2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, 2d canvas context doesn't have native methods to do that. So you have to write your own transform logic (or use the external library).

There are several demos that may be useful for you:

http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html
http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html

I adopted your demo to combine it with the second code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/u9ck6b2q/3/

```
op = new html5jp.perspective(canvas.getContext('2d'), imageObj);
image.image(canvas);

op && op.p.ctxd.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
op && op.draw([
    [dashed.leftTop.attrs.x,
    dashed.leftTop.attrs.y],
    [dashed.rightTop.attrs.x,
    dashed.rightTop.attrs.y],
    [dashed.rightBottom.attrs.x,
    dashed.rightBottom.attrs.y],
    [dashed.leftBottom.attrs.x,
    dashed.leftBottom.attrs.y],
    [dashed.leftTop.attrs.x,
    dashed.leftTop.attrs.y]
  ]);
```

Comment: thank you so much! also, it's possible that you add something like Transformer you did? 
var tr = new Konva.Transformer();
tr.attachTo(target);


var sk = new Konva.Skew();
sk.attachTo(target);

very useful feature.

Comment: I need to synchronize picture with selection, so that when the picture moves, selected zone also moves. in your example: https://jsfiddle.net/u9ck6b2q/3/

Comment: and something like cutter, without image, just WHITE COLOR inside

Comment: @EagleSBG I think the simplest solution will be to add them all into one draggable group.

Comment: i have added move logic: lines 235-250, pls help me to synch with a pic, what i missed? https://jsfiddle.net/u9ck6b2q/4/

Comment: @EagleSBG on image move you change a position of each anchor. Then image drawing adjusted from that positions. It produces double result of image change (1 - position changed by drag&drop, 2 - drawing changed from anchors positions). I still suggest to use a draggable group. That will simplify the logic.